# Backup database in mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following script to make a backup to my database:

```
declare @fecha varchar(MAX)
declare @archivo varchar(MAX)
set @fecha = SUBSTRING(Convert(Varchar(10), GetDate(),105),1,2)+SUBSTRING(Convert(Varchar(10), GetDate(),105),4,2)+SUBSTRING(Convert(Varchar(10), GetDate(),105),7,4)+'_'+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(Varchar(10), GetDate(),108),1,2)+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(Varchar(10), GetDate(),108),4,2)
set @archivo ='F:\GFE_Client'+@fecha+'.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE GFE-Client
TO DISK = @archivo
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'D_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of GFE-Client';
GO
```

The name of my database include a "-" and I can´t change this.

I have a way to replace the "-" in the script that does the backup?

Comment: What's the problem? Why do you want to replace the "-"?

Comment: When I try to run the SQL file that backup, returns incorrect syntax near '-'.

Comment: Enclose your database name with brackets. `BACKUP DATABASE [GFE-Client]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your database name with brackets.

> BACKUP DATABASE [GFE-Client]